# tesseract undefined symbol: pixGenerateHalftoneMask

Tags: linux, warnings, ocr, tesseract, symbols

hi everyone I just installed tesseract-ocr. But when i start to use it. show this kind of error. i dont`t know how to fix it. please help me.

```
 tesseract test.png test.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
tesseract: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.so.4: undefined symbol: pixGenerateHalftoneMask
```

Answer (score 0):

You have outdated leptonica version (e.g. update leptonica).

Answer (score 0):

I just removed leptonica-1.73 then everything become OK.